# Macro to delete only values of 0.00 and not 150.00, etc

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro to search a column and delete the entire row if the value is 0.00. The problem is it also deletes all rows that contain that string i.e 140.00, 150.00, etc... so i'm losing good data. Not sure how to fix?

My Macro:

```
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("J5", ActiveSheet.Range("J65536").End(xlUp))
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("0.00", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: do the cells only contain the number?

Comment: could search for `" 0.00"` (there's a space in front) if there's other text contained in the cell, otherwise add `LookAt:=xlWhole` to your `.Find` parameters

Comment: Yes the cells only contain numbers

Comment: adding the space seems to have worked. Saved me a lot of time. Don't know why i didn't think of that.

Comment: Thanks what a great help

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("J").Cells.Count to 5 Step -1
    If Range("J" & i).Value = 0# Then Range("J" & i).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

Give it a try and let me know your comments

Answer (score 0):

you can delete wanted rows in one shot:

```
With Range("J4", Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)) '<--| assuming "J4" cell is the "header" of data in cells from "J5" down to last column J not empty cell
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0.00" '<--| filtre cells whose content is "0.00"
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '<--| if any cell found other than header then delete corresponding rows (skipping headers)
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Worked and seemed to go faster. Thanks